# PHPExcel load file too long

Tags: phpexcel

I have [.xls file](http://ferrum-n.ru/images/pracelist/price.xls) (340Kb), but when I try to load it - process takes about 15 minutes.

Can you help me, what problem with the file?

My code:

```
$file_type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify( $file_name );
$OR = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($file_type);
$E = $OR->load( $file_name );
```

Thanks!

=============================================================

Update:

I found, that on load a large number of notices appears:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: -1120109318 in /PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php
```

function `_GetInt2d`
line `return ord($data[$pos]) | (ord($data[$pos+1]) << 8);`

function `_GetInt4d`
line `$_or_24 = ord($data[$pos + 3]);`

function `_GetInt4d`
line `return ord($data[$pos]) | (ord($data[$pos+1]) << 8) | (ord($data[$pos+2]) << 16) | $_ord_24;`

Maybe this is the problem?
Is it file problem or PHPExcel?

With `$OR->setReadDataOnly(true);` all works fine.

Comment: Are there any options for verbose output during the loading process? That might give you a clue where it's hung up.

Comment: File size isn't as important as number of worksheets, rows, columns and cells..... do you need to load all sheets? can you load just a subset of data? Do you need style information, or just the raw data?

Comment: Looks like the file has a lot of problems; how is it created?

Comment: Mark, I don't know